# Super short and awesome variable name in C#

Tags: c#, variables

Probably a bit silly of a problem, but I have this one variable (a part of a library) that I am using all the time (it gives me access to a whole lot of properties and functions). I want it to be as short as possible, and, preferably, something easy to write. jQuery's "$" would be pretty great, but that doesn't work, neither do any numbers or symbols I tried. I *could* use something like "s", but I was hoping there'd be something even better (and something that's not just one boring Latin letter).

So what would be SO's best super-short-and-awesome variable name?

Comment: $ seems like a pain as it involves holding down shift.  :)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  The time you save typing it won't be enough to compensate unreadable code.  see the jball advise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd also advise not to do that - it's much better to use a name that explains the purpose of the variable.

However in the spirit of answering the question: You could use underscore: `_`.

It's a valid variable name in C# (and many other langauges). This isn't a new idea by the way - I have seen some frameworks in C and Python that use underscore as a method that takes a string meaning *this string should be localized*.

Comment: http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/ :)

Comment: Ok, no, tried `_` and it was worse than I'd imagined. So now I just have to make up something meaningful :P Thanks anyway :)

Comment: g-d forbid you should write meaningful code unless forced to....

Answer (score 20):

Because I have intellisense in Visual Studio and the C# compiler will not use more memory (produce larger MSIL) for code using a longer variable name, I would call it `somethingMeaningful`.

Comment: If it's a field or parameter, the binary will be (slightly) larger.  However, you're still right.

Comment: Size won't really change since it's compiled, true, but IMHO something like `s` is a bit more convenient to use (in this situation) than `somethingReallyMeaningful`, even with IntelliSense...

Comment: If you want to optimize your typing time using IntelliSense, you could maybe start it with an uncommon letter (z?) so that IntelliSense pulls it up faster. Or even `Zzz` so it would be the only hit on IntelliSense.

Comment: And with Resharper's Goto Symbol Ctrl-Alt-Shift-N navigation is also not a problem

Answer (score 18):

Obviously the best answer is to use a unicode snowman:

## ☃

Comment: error CS1056: Unexpected character '☃' (joking, I know :)

Comment: @jball I don't support any language that you can't name your variables snowman

Comment: @hunter, well, `int snowman` works, just not `int ☃`...

Comment: -1, cause I'd regret not having downvoted this answer if I ever saw a variable like that...

Comment: C# must disallow certain unicode blocks. No fun at all. At least you can use the polar bear: ᵔᴥᵔ (Edit: Never mind. Resharper liked it though!)

Comment: To dispose hunter's carrot, do a `☃.Melt()` ;-)

Comment: +1 @hunter. P.S. that won't compile during summer

Comment: @Lucero to ensure that the carrot can't be lost, do `☃.insert_carrot.freeze`.

Answer (score 3):

RBDD.  Stands for "Really Bad Design Decision."  In fact, make it all lower case, to emphasize the "bad" part.

```
public static class rbdd
{
  // put bad stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about ssaa (short for super-short-and-awesome)?