# Variable naming discussion: C# vs JavaScript?

Tags: c#, javascript, conventions

I was reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380185/super-short-and-awesome-variable-name-in-c-closed) and it left me wondering...

Why is it wrong to use a variable named `_` in `C#` for a intensively used library (should one ever surface), but perfectly fine to use `$` for the same purpose under `JavaScript`?

Comment: I'm convinced that C# API designers are paid by the word.

Comment: now that's a better question, in some scripting languages is required to prepend $ variable names. That doesn't mean that Javascript devs suggest the use of $ for a single char variable, I'd say is must likely tradition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguably because `_` (as a variable name **by itself**) carries no meaning, and a longer/more meaningful identifier doesn't take much longer to type (with Visual Studio's intellisense). Not to mention the fact that the C# compiler won't "penalize" you (in terms of increasing the size of your compiled program) for having a longer identifier.

In the case of jQuery, however, using `someIdentifier` instead of `$` actually *does* increase the final size of your javascript file. By a couple of characters, sure -- but multiply that by a couple of orders of magnitude (number times repeated in your file, number of times your file will be downloaded by a client's browser, etc.) and a few characters could start to matter, especially if your site experiences a lot of traffic.

Finally, you also have to take into account the community involved. In the Javascript community, for example, jQuery is so commonplace that even if you don't use it in your application, anyone remotely familiar with it will know what `$` means. There's nothing in C# (that I'm aware of) that has that level of visibility, and since it's a compiled language with a powerful IDE, there's really no need for a jQuery-like "`$`"-equivalent prefix.

My two cents.

Comment: I disagree with the statement that `_` carries no meaning. Most programmers I know would look at a variable prefixed with `_` as being a private variable in the local scope that is used for encapsulating a public property.

Comment: @entens Sorry, I meant no meaning as a variable name *by itself*. Using it as a prefix, however, is something entirely different from what's being asked here.

Comment: eh i seem to have missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Define "perfectly fine". A variable called `_` is syntactically valid in C# but, as you may notice one or two (or every single) respondent saying in that question, it avails you very, very little to use a naming convention like that, while rendering your code highly difficult to read.

Comment: Well, no one seems to be against it in the case of jQuery. That's my point.